# How to retrieve the datetime objects from an array

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I have written the following code:

```
tnow=datetime.datetime.now()
date_string = tnow.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(f"datestring ={date_string}")
timeIntervals=["09:15:00","09:45:00","10:15:00","10:45:00","11:15:00","11:45:00","12:15:00","12:45:00","01:15:00","01:45:00","02:15:00","02:45:00","03:15:00","03:30:00"]
DatetimeIntervals=[]
now=datetime.datetime.now()
current_date=now.date()
for timeinterval in timeIntervals:
    DatetimeIntervals.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string+' '+timeinterval,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    print(timeinterval)
for i,timeint in enumerate(DatetimeIntervals):
    print(timeint)
for i,timeint in enumerate(DatetimeIntervals):
    nexttime=timeint[i+1]
    while(datetime.datetime.now()>timeint and datetime.datetime.now()<nexttime):
        #here check if trade is active or not.  
        time.sleep(2)
```

Now i am not able to compare the datetime in the above while loop as a result i get the error-

TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable
Any other way how i can get around this problem?

Comment: Which *line* is throwing the error? What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: The error says you are trying to Index *the datetime object*, not any container *of datetime objects*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the problem `datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable` because enumerate provides two-parameters. One is an index and another is a value. You can't get the index of the enumerated value.

Try this

```
if i < len(DatetimeIntervals)-1:
    nexttime = DatetimeIntervals[i+1]
```

Avoid use `nexttime=timeint[i+1]`. Rather use

```
tnow = datetime.datetime.now()
date_string = tnow.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(f"datestring ={date_string}")
timeIntervals = ["09:15:00", "09:45:00", "10:15:00", "10:45:00", "11:15:00", "11:45:00",
                 "12:15:00", "12:45:00", "01:15:00", "01:45:00", "02:15:00", "02:45:00", "03:15:00", "03:30:00"]
DatetimeIntervals = []
now = datetime.datetime.now()
current_date = now.date()
for timeinterval in timeIntervals:
    DatetimeIntervals.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(
        date_string+' '+timeinterval, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    print(timeinterval)
for i, timeint in enumerate(DatetimeIntervals):
    print(timeint)
for i, timeint in enumerate(DatetimeIntervals):
    if i < len(DatetimeIntervals)-1:
        nexttime = DatetimeIntervals[i+1]
        while(datetime.datetime.now() > timeint and datetime.datetime.now() < nexttime):
            # here check if trade is active or not.
            time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: In this i get     nexttime = DatetimeIntervals[i+1]

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: need to substract 1 form the len if i < len(DatetimeIntervals) -1: